# Rota ASP.NET não recebe o parâmetro na Action após ser configurada

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu mapeei uma nova rota no meu site assim:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "PaymentEdit",
            "Payment/{type}",
            new { controller = "Contributor", action = "Payment" },
            new { type = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Minha Action é essa:

```
[AutorizacaoFilterAttribute]
public ActionResult Payment(string rt)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(rt);
    return View();
}
```

O controller se chama Contributor, está certinho. Porém quando eu chamo a url: `http://localhost:54345/Contributor/Payment/1` o ´Debug´ não me retorna nada no `Output`. 
Já fiz o mesmo tipo de rota em outra Action e funciona normal, ao meu ver está a mesma coisa, segue o código:

Rota:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Home",
            "Image/{produtoid}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Image"},
            new { produtoid = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult Image(string id)
{  
        Debug.WriteLine(id);
        return View();
}
```

Quando eu chamo a url `http://localhost:54345/Home/Image/2107209300` o `Debug`me retorna normalmente o valor `2107209300` Eu já testei diversas vezes de diversos modos, e não consigo encontrar a diferença entre as duas.

Meu Route.config completo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace SiteTeste
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Home",
                "Image/{produtoid}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Image"},
                new { produtoid = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Contributor",
                "Payment/{type}",
                new { controller = "Contributor", action = "Payment" },
                new { type = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Alterando a rota e inserindo ela em **primeiro** lugar no route.config, quando passo a url: http://localhost:54345/Contributor/Payment/41242 tenho o seguinte erro:

> A entrada de restrição 'type' na rota com a URL 'Contributor/Payment/{type}' deve ter um valor de cadeia de caracteres ou ser de um tipo que implementa IRouteConstraint.

Segue a rota editada:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Contributor",
            "Contributor/Payment/{type}",
            new { controller = "Contributor", action = "Payment" },
            new { type = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: O que você chama de `views` são, na verdade, `actions`.

Comment: @LINQ Sim, são as actions

Comment: Poste o seu arquivo `RouteConfig.cs` completo. Aproveitando, tente colocar a rota do pagamento antes das outras.

Comment: Tem com certeza choque de rotas, poste o arquivo completo de `RouteConfig.cs`

Comment: Editado pessoal !

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti a rota de nome `Home` o `produtoid` é de qual tipo

Comment: @VirgilioNovic `string`, assim como a type da `Contributor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você estava chamando errado na sua primeira duvida, a `url` correta para a rota criada:

```
Payment/123
Payment/abc
```

e a outra forma que estava tentando fazer estava errado e caia na rota padrão `Default` que não tem `type` e sim `id` configurado.

***Configuração reformulada:***

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Home",
        "Image/{produtoid}",
        new {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Image",
            productid = UrlParameter.Optional
        },
        new { produtoid = @"\w+" }
     );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Contributor",
        "Payment/{type}",
        new {
            controller = "Contributor",
            action = "Payment",
            type = UrlParameter.Optional
        },
        new { type = @"\w+" }
     );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Contributor_Payment",
        "Contributor/Payment/{type}",
        new
        {
            controller = "Contributor",
            action = "Payment",
            type = UrlParameter.Optional
        },
        new { type = @"\w+" }
     );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { 
            controller = "Home", 
            action = "Index", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional 
            }
    );    
}
```

observe que foi criado agora 1 rota adicional, então vai funcionar

```
+------------------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
|   Controler      |      Action          |       Url                      |
+------------------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
|   Home           |       Image          |   Home/Image/123456            |
+------------------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
|   Contributor    |      Payment         |   Payment/123456               |
+------------------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
|   Contributor    |      Payment         |   Contributor/Payment/123456   |
+------------------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
```

sendo que as duas últimas cairam no mesmo `Controller` e `Action` como uma forma de exemplificar, um outra fator a rota `Default` é sempre a última e por fim foi adicionado regras na rota isso impede que seja executada rotas que não batem com a regra, no caso em si vai aceitar texto na duas rotas, mas, [isso pode ser limitado a números ou até a configurações customizadas de regras](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs).

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Creating a Route Constraint (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs)
- [Trabalhando com Limites de Rotas (Route Constraints) no ASP.NET MVC](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3061/trabalhando-com-limites-de-rotas-route-constraints-no-aspnet-mvc.aspx)
- [ASP.NET MVC routing by string id? <sup>SOEn</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618037/asp-net-mvc-routing-by-string-id)
- [must have a string value or be of a type which implements IRouteConstraint  <sup>SOEn</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028698/must-have-a-string-value-or-be-of-a-type-which-implements-irouteconstraint)
- [Learn About ASP.NET MVC](https://www.asp.net/mvc)
- [Creating custom route constraints in ASP.NET MVC](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/3/creating_custom_route_constraints_in_asp_net_mvc)

Comment: Cara, eu não acredito que todo esse tempo(4 meses) eu acreditava que  a rota Image funcionava,inclusive, eu tinha essa duvida, porque eu recebo "produtoid" sendo que na view Image eu recebo um parametro chamado `id` e funciona. Antes da sua resposta eu tinha conseguido corrigir o problema, inclusive vou responder minha pergunta com a minha solução, porém a sua é a mais correta, +1.

Comment: só me responde uma coisa, o que é `\w+` ?

Comment: Expressão regular para limitar aquele paramento a um texto, ou seja, aceita qualquer texto, se pode limitar por exemplo somente aceita números, etc ... é uma regra na url isso é bom, @LeonardoBonetti, dá uma lida no Route Constraints que tem um link na resposta.

Comment: Entendi, vou ler sim com toda  certeza ! Obrigado Virgilio, também não sabia o que era essa Constraint, pensava que era a própria variavel.