# É possível saber em qual routes.Map() a chamada da uma Action caiu? ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Depois [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230184/rota-asp-net-n%C3%A3o-recebe-o-par%C3%A2metro-na-action-ap%C3%B3s-ser-configurada/230199?noredirect=1#comment471329_230199) me surgiu a duvida, é possivel eu saber em qual map de rota a minha Action utilizou? Exemplo:

Tenho dois `routes.MapRoute()`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Home",
    "Image/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Image",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    },
    new { id = @"\w+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

E uma Action

```
 public ActionResult Image(string id)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(id);
        return View();

    }
```

Ambos `Map.Route()` irão funcionar, só que nesse caso iria cair na primeira opção(porque ambas estão corretas porém a que vem primeiro é a utilizada), mas se o `Map.Route()` chamado "Home" não funcionasse, eu não saberia em qual `Map.Route()` estaria caindo quando chamo a Action "Image"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, você consegue acessar os dados da rota já que sua controller faz herança de `Controller` ou `ApiController`

```
public ActionResult Image(string id)
{
    //Caso seja ApiController
    var route = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Route.RouteTemplate;
    Console.WriteLine(route);

    //Caso seja apenas Controller
    var route = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Route as Route;
    Console.WriteLine(route.Url);
}
```

O resultado no meu caso fica como: `"api/{controller}/{action}"`

Comment: RouteTemplate existe?

Comment: Opa, já arrumei a resposta, o RouteTemplate só existe no caso da herança ser no ApiController.

Comment: Certinho, eu pesquisei e vi que o name não é guardado :( mas de qualquer forma já resolve da mesma maneira ! +1